# The latex code for a table in Latex

Tags: tables

Can someone show me the latex code for this table?
[image]

Thanks all!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. I suggest to use this tool without your MWE: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: See some introductory text about writing tables. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: See: https://mathpix.com/, https://github.com/lukas-blecher/LaTeX-OCR or https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/pu3xnh/mathpix_free_equivalent/

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" site. Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows what you have done about your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[2cm,c]Q[1.5cm,c]Q[1.5cm,c]Q[1.5cm,c]Q[1.5cm,c]Q[1.5cm,c]},rows={0.7cm,m},vlines,hlines,hline{3}={solid,1pt}}
        \SetCell[r=2] {m} {dim \\ $Q^{d}(B(3))$} & $u=0$ & \SetCell[c=4]{c} $u\geq 0$ \\
                                               & $s=0$ & $s=1$ & $s=2$ & $s=3$ & $s>3$\\
                                    $t=0$      & $1$ & $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$\\
                                    $t> 0$  & $1$ & $1$ & $2$ & $2$ & $2$\\                                        
    \end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]